# SQL unable to resume data movement after manual failover

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

We have a 3 node availability group, PRIMARY, a synchronized none readable replica and a async readable replica. We are currently doing an in place upgrade to 2016, both secondaries have been upgraded and patched so I am manually failing over the primary to the none readable secondary sync replica. When I fail over, the new PRIMARY appears fine, the readable async replica appears fine but the now new secondary goes into a none synchronized state. I have attempted to resume data movement but it fails with an error message about object explorer unable to refresh.

In the error logs I can see these errors:

> ***The database 'X' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 706 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>
> AlwaysOn Availability Groups data movement for database 'X' has been suspended for the following reason: "system" (Source ID 7; Source string: 'SUSPEND_FROM_REVALIDATION'). To resume data movement on the database, you will need to resume the database manually. For information about how to resume an availability database, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Error: 948, Severity: 20, State: 102.***

I assumed this might be due to the primary being 2016 and this server being 2012 but apparently this is a legacy issue on this box, it a DEV box so not been a major concern.

Does anybody know why this is happening and what to do to resolve this?

Comment: IS the primary patched to sql2016 ?

Comment: I think this is one for https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: not patched the primary to sql 2016 yet no, wanting to failover gracefully before I patch the primary but data movement stuck in paused when failing over

Comment: I think this is because of the version difference, 2016 can read from a 2012 Primary but not the other way when the failover occurs until the 2012 server has been upgraded. I will confirm this next week when I upgrade.